# Platform independent example of subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, linux

I have the following piece of code which needs to be platform independent which isn't at the moment:

This works in windows to start the python script "pb_cli.py"

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["python","pb_cli.py","get_token","60"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, cwd = '.',)
(result, err) = proc.communicate()
```

However - this does not seem to work in Linux. In Linux, I need to do this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["python pb_cli.py get_token 60"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, cwd = '.',)
(result, err) = proc.communicate()
```

When I try to use the Linux version on windows, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Documents\Code\STAGE\cli>python move_users.py --input=users.txt --username --source_account=531 --destination_account=9
'"python pb_cli.py get_token 60"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

When I try to use the Windows version on Linux, it just starts the interpretor.

Anybody have any idea on how to make this code uniform across platforms?

Comment: Can you try Windows version on Linux again, it looks perfectly fine to me. Also, no need for shell=True.

Comment: How about skipping Popen entirely and doing `import pb_cli; pb_cli.get_token(60)`?

Comment: I don't think you should combine having a argument list with `shell=True` (windows version). Have you tried without it? Also, `cwd="."` is redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any OS, when `shell=False` (which it is by default), the first argument should be a list:

```
Popen(["python","pb_cli.py","get_token","60"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

When `shell=True`, the first argument should be a string:

```
subprocess.Popen("python pb_cli.py get_token 60", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

PS. Try to avoid using `shell=True` since it can be a [security risk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

---

The actual rule is a bit more complicated. [The docs say](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments),

> If passing a single string, either shell must be True (see below) or
>   else the string must simply name the program to be executed without
>   specifying any arguments.

which implies that you can pass a string when `shell=False` as long at it is simply the name of the program to be executed. However, if you stick to the above rule, you won't go wrong.

Comment: I removed `shell=True` and the version which has the parameters in a list works now. Cheers!